# Reading and Displaying Mapinfo Data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mapinfo

I would like to know if there is a simple way to read and display files generated by *Mapinfo* (like .DAT, .MAP, .TAB), in *Matlab*.

Comment: Do you have the Mapping Toolbox?

Comment: Dear all, since I had access to a workstation on which MapInfo was installed, I could translate .TAB files into .shp files. However, it would be anyways interesting to have a matlab script that does this conversion. But now there is a new problem: I want to read those .shp files in Matlab: (the file CH.shp is stored in the matlab working directory), I try to read it with `ZIP_CH=shaperead('CH.shp')` but this does not work. The following error message is appearing: `Unsupported shape type PolygonZ (type code = 15).`

Comment: Can someone explain what the problem is and does someone know a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, [from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40613/importing-shp-file-in-matlab), Matlab can't read 3D shapefiles with elevation data, only 2D shapefiles, so you need to convert them from 3D to 2D shapefiles.  If you have ArcMap, you can do [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=296920).